# How to capitalize \zcref as \Cref does?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, capitalization, zref

I'm trying to migrate from cleveref to zref-clever, due to the former incompatibility with pdfmanagement phase-III.

Is it possible to have a variant of zref-clever and zref-vario that outputs "Section 2" instead of "section 2"?

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{zref-vario}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\title{Kant nonsense}
\author{Me}

\let\oldlabel\label
\renewcommand{\label}[1]{\oldlabel{#1}\zlabel{#1}}

\begin{document}

% zref: "2"
% zcref: "section 2"
% zvref: "section 2 on page 3"
% nameref: "Kant"

I like \zcref{end}.\\
\zcref{end} is my favorite. % <--- here I would like a \zCref variant

\section{Kant}
\kant
\section{End}
\label{end}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `pdfmanagement phase-III` is the wrong wording. phase-III is about tagging.  Apart from this: it is not a bad idea to switch to zref-clever, but if you find an incompability, please report it also (with a small complete example) at https://github.com/latex3/tagging-project so that we can take a look at it. The tagging project needs feedback from users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent to `\Cref` in `zref-clever` is the `S` option (for "sentence"), which is an alias to `capfirst=true,noabbrevfirst=true`, meaning it ensures a capitalized and not abbreviated name for the first type block in given call to `\zcref`. So, all you need is `\zcref[S]{<label>}`. The same for `\zvref[S]{<label>}`.

Regarding:

```tex
\let\oldlabel\label
\renewcommand{\label}[1]{\oldlabel{#1}\zlabel{#1}}
```

you shouldn't do this. It may lead to trouble in some scenarios and it is actually not needed. If you have the latest version of `zref-clever` it already uses the new `label` hook made available by the kernel and sets both a `\label` and a `\zlabel` for a given call of `\label`. So you can just use `\label` already.

Now, if you are doing this in your actual document and not getting duplicate label warnings, it may be that you are using an older version of `zref-clever`. Ideally, if you can, you should update.  On the other hand, you report to be using `\DocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-III}`, so you seem to have an up to date TeX installation and, probably, were getting duplicate label warnings. Either way, you shouldn't redefine `\label` like that.

In full:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{zref-vario}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\title{Kant nonsense}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

% zref: "2"
% zcref: "section 2"
% zvref: "section 2 on page 3"
% nameref: "Kant"

I like \zcref{end}.\\
\zcref[S]{end} is my favorite. % <--- For a "\zCref" variant, use the "S" option.
\zvref[S]{end} too.

\section{Kant}
\kant
\section{End}
\label{end}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The feature you are mentioning for labels appeared this June, so it's not shipped in TeXLive 2023: https://github.com/gusbrs/zref-clever/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#v040-2023-06-14 With version 0.3.6 (2023-02-21) it does not return the duplicate warning

Comment: @Polizi8 Yes, it has been released with version v0.4.0 from 2023-06-14 and requires the 2023-06-01 kernel. But it is definitely available in TeX Live 2023 already. If that's what you're running, it is only a matter of updating it.