How convert cleveref & varioref to zref-cleveref & zref-vario?
A book-length document heavily uses cleveref and varioref, so will not compile if I use:
\DocumentMetadata{
   testphase={phase-III,math,table},
    pdfstandard=a-2u
   }

(It also uses crossreftools; I'm not sure if that also clashes.)
I want to replace of cleveref with zref-clever (and varioref with zref-vario). Rather than edit the entire document, I want to write cover functions such as \cref that will simply call commands from zref-clever, etc.
Question: How do I still accomplish what the cleveref commands \crefname, \crefformat, etc., do?
The following source illustrates the commands that need substitutes.
% PDF METADATA PREP
\DocumentMetadata{%
  % testphase={phase-III,math,table}, % TO ENABLE!
  lang=en-US,
  pdfstandard=a-2u}

\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt,leqno]{memoir}

% Create showboth.sty to show command and its output
\usepackage{filecontents}   
\begin{filecontents}{showboth.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2020/02/021]
\ProvidesPackage{showboth}[2018/11/27   % today 
Print result of code and display the code, Ulrich Diez] 
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341616/how-use-fancyvrb-to-show-both-result-and-verbatim-text
% Load showboth.sty late!
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
%
\makeatletter
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=12 %
\UD@firstoftwo{%
  \endgroup%
  \newcommand\UDEndlreplace[2]{\romannumeral0\@UDEndlreplace{#2}#1^^M\relax{}}%
  \newcommand*\@UDEndlreplace{}%
  \long\def\@UDEndlreplace#1#2^^M#3\relax#4#5{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#3}%
    { #5{#4#2}}{\@UDEndlreplace{#1}#3\relax{#4#2#1}{#5}}%
  }%
}{}%
\newcommand\UDcollectOneVerbArg{\@UDOneVerbArg{\@UDcollectOneVerbArg}}%
\newcommand\@UDOneVerbArg[3]{%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \catcode`\{=1 %
  \catcode`\ =10 %
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup
  {\catcode`\}=2 \@@UDOneVerbArg{#1}{#2}{#3}{}}%
  {\do\{\@@UDOneVerbArg{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}%
\newcommand\@@UDOneVerbArg[4]{%
  \do\ %
  \catcode`\^^M=12 %
  \long\def\@tempb##1#4{%
    \edef\@tempb{##1}%
    \@onelevel@sanitize\@tempb
    \expandafter\UDEndlreplace\expandafter{\@tempb}{#2}{\def\@tempb}%
    \expandafter#1\expandafter{\@tempb}{#3}{#4}%
  }%
  \@tempb
}%
\newcommand\@UDcollectOneVerbArg[3]{%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
  #2{#3}{#1}%
}%
% Generic stuff for reading arguments "verbatim" done.
\newcommand\showboth{\UDcollectOneVerbArg{^^J}{\innershowboth}}%
\newcommand\innershowboth[2]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\scantokens{{#2} --- \Verb{#2}\begingroup\catcode`\X=14 X}}%<-Raises error as \Verb doesn't accept opening braces as delimiter.
  {\scantokens{{#2} --- \Verb#1#2#1\begingroup\catcode`\X=14 X}}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
 
% UTILITY PACKAGES
\usepackage{xstring} 
\usepackage{suffix}

% FONT & LANGUAGE PACKAGES
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[russian,french,ngerman,polish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[amsthm,thmslshape,trueslanted]{newtx}

% GRAPHICS PACKAGES
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,theorems}

% THEOREMS PACKAGES
\usepackage{thmtools}

% LISTS PACKAGES
\usepackage{enumitem}

% BIBLIOGRAPHY PACKAGES
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{backref=true}

%%  CROSS-REFERENCING PACKAGES
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{datetime2} % to satisfy "\today" in \hypersetup

\usepackage[nospace,english]{varioref}
    \renewcommand\reftextcurrent{\unskip}% no ''on this page'' etc.

\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  linktocpage=true,linktoc=all,
  hyperfigures=true,
  hyperfootnotes=true,
  pdfdate={\today},
}
% Allow link to page with label -- hyperref patch by Martin Scharrer
% cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19416/9237
\makeatletter
\let\orig@Hy@EveryPageAnchor\Hy@EveryPageAnchor
\def\Hy@EveryPageAnchor{%
    \begingroup
    \hypersetup{pdfview=Fit}%
    \orig@Hy@EveryPageAnchor
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
%
\usepackage{hyperxmp}

\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}

%% Allow ref to section n, not section m.n
%%% Christian Hupfe, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383608/13492
\usepackage[user,hyperref]{zref}
\RegisterPostLabelHook{\zlabel}
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{section}{\arabic{section}}
\zref@addprop{main}{section}
\newcommand{\crefsec}[1]{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
    \cref{#1}% fall back to usual \ref if no such zref - specific label. 
  }{\hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{Section~\zref@extract{#1}{section}}%
  }}
\makeatother

\usepackage{crossreftools}
% Fix to crossreftools - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512175/13492
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@@crtextr@ct@ref}[2]{%
  \expandafter\@@@crtextr@ct@ref\expandafter{\detokenize{#2}}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\@@@crtextr@ct@ref}[2]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname r@#1\endcsname\relax
  \crt@refundefined%
  \else
  \expandafter\expandafter\csname crt@ref@splitter@#2\endcsname\csname r@#1\endcsname%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

% EDITING & TESTING PACKAGES
\usepackage[notref,notcite]{showkeys}
\usepackage{showboth}

% FONT SETTINGS
% Fix spacing after colon:
\sfcode`:=\sfcode`;
\newcommand{\colonlist}{:\spacefactor2000\relax\space\ignorespaces}

% GRAPHICS SETTINGS
\AtBeginDocument{\colorlet{defaultcolor}{.}}
\colorlet{mythmback}{gray!5!white}

\usetikzlibrary{babel}

% STYLE SETTINGS
% Handle refs to subsections, which are unnumbered 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660430/13492
\NewCommandCopy{\oldsubsection}{\subsection}
\newcounter{subsec}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{s}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\subsec}{\oldsubsection}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subsec}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{subsec}%
  \def\cref@currentlabel{[subsec][\arabic{subsec}][]#1}%
  \def\@currentlabelname{#1}%
  \oldsubsection*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}%
}
\makeatother

% THEOREMS SETTINGS
\swapnumbers % Invert numbers/labels

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
  postheadspace=0.5em plus 2pt minus 2pt,
  notefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\thfamily,
]{thmstyle}
%
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  postheadspace=0.5em plus 2pt minus 2pt,
  notefont=\sffamily\bfseries, 
  notebraces={}{},
  headformat=\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\thfamily,
]{namedthmstyle}
\makeatletter
%
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont= \sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
  postheadspace=0.5em plus 2pt minus 2pt,
  notefont=\sffamily\mdseries,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
]{defstyle}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, style=thmstyle, numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}
\counterwithin{theorem}{chapter}

\declaretheorem[
  style=namedthmstyle,
  name=Theorem,
  title = {},
  numberlike=theorem
]{namedtheorem}
\counterwithin{namedtheorem}{chapter}

\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{%
    breakable,
    parbox=false,
    colback=mythmback,
    frame hidden,colframe=mythmback,sharp corners,
    left=2pt,right=2pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,
    }
\tcolorboxenvironment{namedtheorem}{% 
    breakable, 
    parbox=false,
    colback=mythmback,
    frame hidden,colframe=mythmback,sharp corners,
    left=2pt,right=2pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,
    }

\declaretheorem[name=Proposition, style=thmstyle, numberlike=theorem]{proposition}

\declaretheorem[name=Definition, style=defstyle, numberlike=theorem]{definition}
\counterwithin{definition}{chapter}

\declaretheorem[
  name=Example,
  style=defstyle,
  numberlike=theorem,
  ]
{example}
\counterwithin{example}{chapter}
\declaretheorem[
  name=Examples,
  style=defstyle,
  numberlike=theorem,
  ]
{examples}
\counterwithin{examples}{chapter}

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headformat=\NAME\NOTE,
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\sffamily\bfseries, 
  notebraces={}{},
  headformat=\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\mdseries,
  numbered=no,
]{bibcommentstyle}
\declaretheorem[
  name={},
  style=bibcommentstyle
]{bibcomment}
\makeatother

% LISTS SETTINGS
% For descriptions added to enumerates...
\newcommand\describe[1]{}
% Method of Skillmon (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/699243/13492):
\makeatletter
\newcommand\gobblepar
  {\@ifnextchar\label{\gobblepar@label}{\@ifnextchar\par{\@gobble}{}}}
\newcommand\gobblepar@label[2]{\label{#2}\gobblepar}
\makeatother
% For examples:
%   Fix to allow grabbing ``note'' field -
%       Ulrike Fischer, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303149/13492
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ditem[1][]{\item{\sffamily\MakeUppercase#1. }%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{#1}\gobblepar}
\makeatother
% For problems:
\def\pitem[#1]{\par
   \setbox0=\hbox{\sffamily(\MakeUppercase#1) \ }
   \item{\sffamily(\MakeUppercase#1) }\par
   \everypar={\hskip\wd0 \everypar={}}
   \nobreak\vskip-\parskip \vskip-\baselineskip
}
    
% Make enumerate labels in thms upright:
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\textup{\arabic*.}}

%% Special lists
\newlist{proplis}{enumerate}{1}
\newenvironment{propertylist}[1]{%
  \setlist[proplis,1]{%
  wide,leftmargin=*,itemsep=0.12ex,
  label=\sffamily\upshape({#1}\arabic*)}\begin{proplis}%
  }
  {\end{proplis}}
  
\newlist{penum}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[penum,1]{%
  label= \sffamily\upshape(\arabic*),
  ref={\arabic*}, % strips formatting!
  widest=99,
}

% For Examples (special crefformat uses for singular/plural)
\newlist{pexenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[pexenum,1]{%
  label= \sffamily\upshape(\arabic*),
  ref={\arabic*}, % strips formatting!
}
\newlist{romcases}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[romcases,1]{%
    label=\sffamily{Case (\roman*):},
    ref=\normalfont{(\roman*)},
    wide,%itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt
%    before=\leavevmode \vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\topsep\relax},
}
\newlist{pfsteps}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[pfsteps,1]{%
  label=\sffamily{Step {\arabic*}:},
  ref=\normalfont{\arabic*},
  wide,
  %itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,
  labelsep=0.75ex,
}
%% Itemize environments allowing labels for cross-referencing
\newcommand*{\textsfdot}[1]{\textsf{#1.}}
\newlist{pfpartsperiod}{description}{1}
\setlist[pfpartsperiod,1]{%
  font=\normalfont\textsf,
  itemindent=0pt,
  wide,
  format={\normalfont\textsfdot}
}
% For exercises:
\newlist{problems}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[problems,1]{%
    label=\bfseries\sffamily\arabic*., % strips formatting!
    ref={\arabic*},
    before={ \subsection[Exercises for Section~\thesection]{\sffamily EXERCISES FOR SECTION~\thesection}\small},
    after={\normalsize},
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@problemsi}{\maybe@thechapter{\thechapter}}
\protected\def\maybe@thechapter#1{%
  \ifnum#1=\value{chapter}%
  \else
    #1.%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\newlist{problemparts}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[problemparts,1]{%
    label=\bfseries\sffamily(\alph*),
    ref={(\alph*)}
}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

%% SHRINK INDENTATION of enumeration first item inside theorem-like environment]
% Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17465/13492
\makeatletter
\newlength{\@thlabel@width}%
\newcommand{\thmhspace}{\settowidth{\@thlabel@width}{\sffamily\upshape(1)}\sbox{\@labels}{\unhbox\@labels\hspace{\dimexpr-\leftmargin+\labelsep+\@thlabel@width-\itemindent}}}
%
\newlength{\@exampleslabel@width}%
\newcommand{\exshspace}{\settowidth{\@exampleslabel@width}{\sffamily\upshape(1)}\sbox{\@labels}{\unhbox\@labels\hspace{\dimexpr-\leftmargin+\labelsep+\@exampleslabel@width-\itemindent}}}
\makeatother

% BIBLIOGRAPHY SETTINGS
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{backref=true}
%
%\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{mylanguagestrings} % external .lbx file!
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  backrefpage = {Cited on page},
  backrefpages = {Cited on pages},
}

% CROSS-REFERENCE SETTINGS

% Commands to use hyperref patch to allow link to page:
% Usage: \crefpagetext{text-to-appar-in-link}{lbl} with usual \label{lbl} for target.
\newcommand{\crefpagetext}[2]{\hyperlink{page.\getpagerefnumber{#2}}{#1} on \cpageref{#2}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefpagetext*[2]{\hyperlink{page.\getpagerefnumber{#2}}{#1}}
\newcommand\crefpage[1]{\cpageref{#1}}

% Fix missing Oxford comma:
\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, and\nobreakspace}

\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypersetup{hidelinks}}}

% cref names and formats:
\crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
\crefname{page}{page}{pages}
\crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefname{namedtheorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefname{definition}{Definition}{Definitions}
\crefname{example}{Example}{Examples}
\crefname{examples}{Examples}{Examples}}
\crefformat{pfstepsi}{#2Step~#1#3}

\crefname{problemsi}{Exercise}{Exercises}
\crefformat{problemsi}{#2Exercise~#1#3}
\crefrangeformat{problemsi}{\textup{(}#3\textup{#1}#4\textup{)}--\textup{(}#5\textup{#2}#6\textup{)}}
\crefformat{problems}{#2Exercises for Section~\textup{#1#3}}
\crefname{problems}{Exercises for Section~\thesection}{Exercises for Section~\thesection}
\crefformat{problempartsi}{#2#1#3}
%
\crefname{penumi}{}{} % do not use ``Item''
\crefformat{penumi}{\textup{(}#2#1#3\textup{)}}
\crefrangeformat{penumi}{\textup{(}#3#1#4\textup{)}--\textup{(}#5#2#6\textup{)}}
\crefname{pexenumi}{Example}{Examples}
\crefformat{pexenumi}{\textup{(}#2#1#3\textup{)}}
\crefrangeformat{pexenumi}{\textup{(}#3#1#4\textup{)}--\textup{(}#5#2#6\textup{)}}
\crefname{proplis}{}{}
\crefformat{proplisi}{#2#1#3}
\crefrangeformat{proplisi}{\textup{(}#3#1#4\textup{)}--\textup{(}#5#2#6\textup{)}}
\crefname{romcasesi}{Case}{Cases}
\crefname{chapter}{Chapter}{Chapters}
\crefname{section}{Section}{Sections}
\crefname{subsec}{subsection}{subsections}
\crefformat{subsec}{#2subsection~``#1''#3} % for my unnumbered subsectionsd
\crefmultiformat{subsec}{subsections~``#2#1#3''}{ and~``#2#1#3''}{,~``#2#1#3''}{ and~``#2#1#3''}
% Special handling of cref's...
\newcommand\crefthmpart[2]{\hyperref[#2]{\namecref{#1}~\labelcref*{#1}~(\ref{#2})}}
\newcommand\crefdef[2]{\hyperref[#2]{\namecref{#2}~\labelcref{#1}~(\ref{#2})}}
\newcommand{\crefex}[2]{\hyperref[#2]{\namecref{#1}~\labelcref*{#1}~(\crtcrefcountervalue{#2})}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefex*[2]{%
  \namecref{#1}~\labelcref*{#1}~(\crtcrefcountervalue{#2})}   
\newcommand\crefexone[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\textup{Example}~\textup{(}\crtcrefcountervalue{#1}\textup{)}}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefexone*[1]{\textup{Example}~\textup{(}\crtcrefcountervalue{#1}\textup{)}}
\newcommand\crefrangeex[3]{\cref{#1}~\crefrange{#2}{#3}}
% special handling of problems environment
\newcommand{\crefprob}[2]{\hyperref[#2]{\namecref{#1}~\labelcref*{#1}~\ref{#2}}}
\newcommand\crefrangeprob[2]{Exercises~\ref{#1}--\ref{#2}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefrangeprob*[2]{\ref{#1}--\ref{#2}}
\newcommand\crefrangeprobpart[2]{\ref{#1}--\ref{#2}}
\newcommand\crefprobandrangeprobpart[3]{\cref{#1}~\ref{#2}--\ref{#3}}

% Allow names in cross-reference to named theorems, etc.,...
% and optional argument names of theorems, etc:
\newcommand{\crefthm}[1]{%
  \IfStrEqCase*{\crtcrefcounter{#1}}{%
    {namedtheorem}{\crefthmname{#1}~(\ref{#1})}%    
    }[\crefthmname{#1}~(\cref{#1})]%
}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefthm*[1]{%
  \IfStrEqCase*{\crtcrefcounter{#1}}{%
    {namedtheorem}{\crefthmname*{#1}~(\ref{#1})}%
    }[\crefthmname*{#1}~(\cref{#1})]%
}

% For upper-casing, i.e., leave names as is:
\newcommand{\crefthmname}[1]{\hyperlink{\crtrefanchor{#1}}{\crtrefname{#1}}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefthmname*[1]{\crtrefname{#1}}

\newcommand\crefthmnamed[2]{\crefthm{#1}~\cref{#2}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefthmnamed*[2]{\crefthm*{#1}~\cref{#2}}

% Cross-reference figure with page, too
\newcommand\figref[1]{\cref{#1} \vpageref{#1}}
    
% Allow names in cross-reference to chapters, sections, subsections
\newcommand*{\crefunit}[1]{\cref{#1} (\nameref*{#1})}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefunit*[1]{\cref*{#1} (\nameref*{#1})}
\newcommand*{\crefunitname}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\nameref{#1}}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefunitname*[1]{\nameref*{#1}}

% Need special ref command for subsecs since they're not numbered
\newcommand*{\crefsubsec}[1]{\cref{#1} (\cpageref{#1})}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefsubsec*[1]{\cref*{#1} (\cpageref{#1})}
\newcommand*{\crefsubsecname}[1]{``\crtrefname{#1}''}
% Added 2020-03-17
% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/reference-name-of-description-list-item-in-latex
\makeatletter
\def\namedlabel#1#2{\begingroup
    #2%
    \def\@currentlabel{#2}%
    \phantomsection\label{#1}\endgroup
}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Links}

\section{Reference methods summary}\label{subsec:ref-mathods}
\begin{itemize}

\item Equation:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \showboth!\cref{eq:pythagoras} \vpageref{eq:pythagoras}!.
        \item \showboth!\cref{eq:one} \vpageref{eq:one}!
    \end{itemize}

\item Named Theorem:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item  \showboth!\crefthm*{thm:big}! 
        \item \showboth!\crefthmname{thm:big}! 
        \item \showboth!\crefthmname*{thm:big}!
    \end{itemize}

\item Theorem with optional argument:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item  \showboth!\crefthm{thm:1-prelim}! 
        \item  \showboth!\crefthm*{thm:1-prelim}! 
        \item \showboth!\crefthmname{thm:1-prelim}! 
        \item \showboth!\crefthmname*{thm:1-prelim}!
        \item \showboth!\cref{thm:1-prelim}! 
        \item \showboth!\crefthmpart{thm:1-prelim}{prelim:part-one}!
    \end{itemize}

\item Ordinary theorem:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \showboth!\cref{thm:another}! 
        \item \showboth!\cref*{thm:another}!
        \item \showboth!\crefthmpart{thm:two-part-thm}{thm-part:two-part-2}!
    \end{itemize}

\item Proof parts
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \showboth!proof of \cref{case:abequal}!
        \item \showboth!proof of \ref{pfitem-necessary}!
        \item \showboth!in \cref{pfstep-two} of the proof!
    \end{itemize}

\item Property lists
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \showboth!\ref{property:two}!
    \end{itemize}

\item Examples and exercises
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \showboth!\cref{exs:several-exs}!
        \item \showboth!\crefex{exs:several-exs}{ex-part:two}!
        \item \showboth!\crefexone{ex-part:two}!
        \item \showboth!\crefrangeex{exs:several-exs}{ex-part:two}{ex-part:three}!
        \item \showboth!\crefthmname{exs:thingies}!
        \item \showboth!\crefex{exs:several-exs}{ex-part:three}!
        \item \showboth!\cref{ex:thingie-one}!
        \item \showboth!\cref{prob:very-first-problem}!
        \item \showboth!\crefprob{prob:second-problem}{prob-part:problem-two-part-b}!
        \item \showboth!\crefrangeprob{prob:very-first-problem}{prob:second-problem}!
        \item \showboth!\crefprob{prob:labeled-problem}{prob-part:problem-one-part-a}!
        \item \showboth!\crefthm{prob:labeled-problem}!
        \item \showboth!\crefthm*{prob:labeled-problem}!
    \end{itemize}

\item Chapter or section reference:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \showboth!\crefunit{sec:stuff}!
        \item \showboth!\crefunit*{sec:stuff}!
        \item \showboth!\crefunitname{sec:stuff}! 
        \item \showboth!\crefunitname*{sec:stuff}!
        \item \showboth!\cref{sec:stuff}! 
        \item \showboth!\cref*{sec:stuff}!
        \item \showboth!\crefsec{sec:stuff}!
    \end{itemize}

\item \emph{Sub}section reference:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \showboth!\cref{subsec:particular}!
        \item \showboth!\cref*{subsec:particular}!
        \item \showboth!\cref{subsec:particular,subsec:ref-mathods}!
        \item \showboth!\crefsubsec*{subsec:particular}!
        \item \showboth!\crefsubsec{subsec:particular}!
        \item \showboth!\crefsubsec*{subsec:particular,subsec:ref-mathods}!
    \end{itemize}

\item Link to page with label
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \showboth!Look at \crefpagetext{the nonsense}{pg:blah-blah}!
    \end{itemize}
    
\item Figure
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \showboth!\cref{fig:picture}!
        \item \showboth!\figref{fig:picture}!
    \end{itemize}   
\end{itemize}

\chapter{Second chapter}\label{chap:the}
\section{This stuff}\label{sec:stuff}

We examine things here.

\subsection*{A particular situation}\label{subsec:particular}
    Here is some text.

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering\framebox[0.5in][c]{\rule{0pt}{0.5in}} 
    \caption{A picture.} \label{fig:picture}
\end{figure}
   
\newpage
\chapter{Third chapter}

\section{Blah-blah-blah}

    Blah-blah-blah-blah blah-blah-blah-blah blah-blah-blah-blah. \label{pg:blah-blah}

\section{Equations, examples, theorems, and exercises}

\subsection*{Equations}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:pythagoras}
    a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation*}\label{eq:one}
    1 > 0 \tag{*}
\end{equation*}

\subsection*{Examples}

\begin{examples}\label{exs:several-exs}
\leavevmode
    \begin{pexenum}
        \item\label{ex-part:one}       A first example.
        \item\label{ex-part:two}      Second example. See also \cref{ex-part:one}.
        \ditem[third example]\label{ex-part:three}    Third example.\qedhere
    \end{pexenum}
\end{examples}

\begin{examples}[several thingies of note]\label{exs:thingies}
    \begin{pexenum}
        \ditem[a first thingie]\label{ex:thingie-one}      Used \verb!\leavevmode! First thingie example.
        \item\label{ex-part:thingies-two}      Second thingie example.
        \item\label{ex-part:thingies-three}    Third example.\qedhere
    \end{pexenum}
\end{examples}

\begin{examples}[thingies]\label{exs:morethingies}
    \begin{pexenum}
        \ditem[a first thingie]\label{ex:more-thingie-one}      Used \verb!\exshspace above!. New thingie example.
        \item\label{ex-part:two-bis}      Second thingie example.
        \item\label{ex-part:three-bis}    Third example.\qedhere
    \end{pexenum}
\end{examples}

\subsection*{Theorems}

\begin{theorem}[Preliminary Result of \NoCaseChange{Euler}]\label{thm:1-prelim}
    \begin{penum}
        \item\label{prelim:part-one} Prelim one.
        \item\label{prelim:part-two} Prelim two.
    \end{penum}
\end{theorem}

\begin{namedtheorem}[The Big \NoCaseChange{Riemann} Theorem]\label{thm:big}
Very important!
    \begin{penum}
        \item\label{big:one} This is as big as you think.
        \item\label{big:two} Perhaps even bigger!
    \end{penum}
\end{namedtheorem}

\begin{proof}
    \begin{romcases}[labelindent=0pt]
        \item \label{case:abequal} $a = b$. Now we see that the conclusion holds
        \item $a \neq b$. In contrast to \cref*{case:abequal}, in this case \dots\qedhere
    \end{romcases}
\end{proof}

Later we use \crefthm{thm:big} or else \crefthmname{thm:big} to deduce consequences. \dots 
And this follows from \nameref{thm:big} \cref{thm:big}.

Return to the ideas begun at the start of \crefunit{sec:stuff}. Or at the beginning of \nameref*{sec:stuff}.

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:another}
Another big result.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}%
    \begin{pfpartsperiod}[labelindent=0pt]
        \item[Sufficiency\label{pfitem-sufficient}]
            First we prove the sufficiency of the condition $a = b$.
        \item[Necessity\label{pfitem-necessary}]
            Finally, we establish the necessity of the condition that $a = b$.
            \qedhere
    \end{pfpartsperiod}
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:two-part-thm}
    \begin{penum}[leftmargin=*]
        \item\label{thm-part:two-part-1} Assertion 1.
        \item\label{thm-part:two-part-2} Assertion 2.
    \end{penum}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
    The set is finite.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
    \begin{pfsteps}[labelindent=0pt]
        \item\label{pfstep-one} First we show this.
        \item\label{pfstep-two} Next we show that.\qedhere
    \end{pfsteps}
\end{proof}

\begin{proposition}\label{prop:two-part-prop}
    \begin{penum}[leftmargin=*]
        \item\label{prop-part:two-part-1} Assertion 1.
    \item\label{prop-part:two-part-2} Assertion 2.
\end{penum}
\end{proposition}


\begin{definition}
A gadget has two properties:
    \begin{propertylist}{P}
        \item\label{property:one} The first property
    \item\label{property:two} Another property:
    \end{propertylist}
\end{definition}

\begin{problems}\label{prob:demo}

    \item\label{prob:very-first-problem}
        Do this one first.

    \pitem[a named problem with parts not preceded by text]\label{prob:second-problem}
    \leavevmode
    \begin{problemparts}
        \item\label{prob-part:problem-two-part-a} Compute the union.
        \item\label{prob-part:problem-two-part-b} Compute the intersection.
    \end{problemparts}
    
    \pitem[named problem with parts preceded by text]\label{prob:labeled-problem-bis}
        There is some text preceding the parts here---hence do \emph{not} use \verb!\leavevmode!.
        \begin{problemparts}
            \item\label{prob-part:problem-three-part-a} Compute the product.
        \item\label{prob-part:problem-three-part-b} Compute the coproduct.
    \end{problemparts}

    \item\label{prob:labeled-problem} No special treatment yet.
        \begin{problemparts}
            \pitem[First part] \label{prob-part:problem-one-part-a} Compute the union once more.
            \item\label{prob-part:problem-one-part-b} Compute the intersection once more.
    \end{problemparts}
\end{problems}
\end{document}


well start to make a smaller example. I at least have neither the will nor the time to debug 800 lines of code. But generally: memoir, enumitem, thmtools, tikz and tcolorbox are not yet compatible with the tagging code, see the status list here https://latex3.github.io/tagging-project/tagging-status/. You would have to replace or adapt the code for all these packages. Consider carefully if you are really up to the task.

My posted code does compile as-is (without the testphase option). I wanted to be sure to include all packages and patches that may conceivably affect the issue. Any help on how to replace some of the crefname and crefformat commands there would be helpful~=!

(69 lines of the code is just to create the showboth.sty package. The document code in question therefore reduces to a "mere" 735 lines!)

For capitalized versions of \cref, already https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/691200/13492 shows how. So my question mainly devolves how to do with zref-clever two things: (1) the equivalent of \crefname; and (2) the equivalent of \crefformat.

I've eliminated more irrelevant code, so exclusive of the 69 lines needed to create package showboth, what's left totals only 699 lines now. Hope this helps further.

as I understand it, Ulrike's point is that replacing cleveref commands is the least of your worries. to make this compatible with the tagging code, you would also have to replace enumitem, tikz, thmtools, memoir and more. that means two things. (1) it isn't clear that answering serves any purpose, even if somebody is able and willing. (2) no answer which could reasonably be given here could possibly make your non-minimal example compile. if you really do just want to know how to replace cleveref, edit your code accordingly. but it won't make the current version work with tagging.

@cfr: Oh! Should I delete the question then?

well, that's really up to you. if you want to switch to zref-clever for other reasons, you could edit to focus on that. if you don't really need all those other packages/classes, you could eliminate those. but if your aim is to use tagging without giving up memoir, enumitem etc. then I don't think the question is a reasonable one in its current form. it basically asks somebody to solve not one but several major upstream compatibility issues and an answer here isn't really the place for that. or if you interpreted the comment differently, you could ask @UlrikeFischer if I misunderstood.
